# Should I need Visa for visit in cyprus?

Tags: visas, bangladeshi-citizens, cyprus, danish-residents

I have Bangladesh national Passport. But I have Permanent residence permit in Denmark. Should I need Visa for visit in cyprus?

Comment: Do you mean Republic of Cyprus or Nothern Cyprus?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the Republic of Cyprus (the southern/Greek, internationally recognized part):

Cyprus is not in the Schengen area, but as a "future joiner" state it does apply some Schengen rules. One of these rules is that holders of residence permits from any Schengen countries are exempt from needing a visa for short visits.

See http://www.mfa.gov.cy/mfa/embassies/embassy_copenhagen.nsf/page09_en/page09_en?OpenDocument

So you do not need a visa, but you should bring both your passport and your Danish residence card.

Comment: It seems like it might be a good idea to answer the question for both parts of the island (even though as far as I can tell the answer is "no" for both parts of the island for this particular traveler).